# Hilt (Android): cannot find symbol return DaggerApp_HiltComponents_ApplicationC.builder()

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

I tried to replace Koin with Hilt (bad idea) for DI and now I'm stuck with this error:
Hilt_App.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
return DaggerApp_HiltComponents_ApplicationC.builder()
^
symbol: variable DaggerApp_HiltComponents_ApplicationC

What is it? How to fix it?

Comment: Make sure that you added Gradle plugin as a dependency and that your Application is annotated with @HiltAndroidApp. If this doesn't solve your problem, post more of your source code.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I used the Jetpack integrations as explained here for the ViewModels https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack and you have to add those dependencies also in the main app module (not only in the modules where you actually use ViewModels).

Comment: and you didn't get anything more meaningful in the error message than what's stated in the question? If that's the case, sounds like a valid reason to file an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Another problem. What if I want to get a shared ViewModel (same instance of the ViewModel for Activity and Fragments). I tried to annotate the ViewModel with @ActivityRetainedScope, but if I use by viewModels() I get different instances of the ViewModel.

Comment: I don't know the answer. Conceptually, to get a shared ViewModel, you need to make sure to call `provide` method with the same instance of Activity. I don't think that just moving ViewModel into retained component achieves that. Maybe that byViewModels() can receive "parent" parameter?

Comment: Please check your JDK version, it should be latest(11.0.10) by going to "Settings" > "Build, Execute, Depolyment" > "Build Tools" > "Gradle"

Answer (score 35):

I got the same error message.
My problem was that I had an old/deprecated gradle dependency.
Make sure to remove following dpenedency from your gradle file:

```
/* DELETE this dependency */
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my issue was resolved.

Comment: That was the reason, Thank you

Answer (score 11):

If you are working on a **modular project**, take care of dependencies!

For example, if you have a `retrofit` dependency in your `data` module, even your `data` module `implemented` in the `app` module, you must add `retrofit` dependency as well or make them transactive with the `api` to be accessible to the `app` module.

Comment: Hey. My app is a single module but I'm facing this issue. This is an intermittent and very frustrating. Do you know any way to fix?

Comment: @SyedZeeshan this error occurs when the provider methods do not have access to the object that is going to be provided. if you could have a sample code I'll help better.

Comment: This is correct answer for me. My `app` module does not implement `retrofit` dependency and could not find Retrofit instance during build.

Answer (score 2):

For those who had the same error but did not miss any dependencies. I had this problem, because I forgot to annotate one class with "@Inject constructor". After I did that, everything worked again.

Comment: What class? And, by "@Inject constructor", do you mean you annotated a constructor with @Inject? If so, the use of quotes is confusing.

Comment: @steve No I forgot to add the "@Inject" to one of my classes constructor and therefore I got this error.

Answer (score 1):

as answered in the guestion comments. The problem was that when using Jetpack integrations as explained here for the ViewModels https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack and you have to add those dependencies also in the main app module (not only in the modules where you actually use ViewModels).

for example , if you have the following in the feature module's build.gradle file:

```
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$hilt_lifecycle"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02"
```

**make sure you add them to the app's build.gradle file as well**

Comment: What if there is only One module? Yeah, my app has only one "app" module but I'm facing this issue...

Answer (score 1):

In my case I forgot to add `package com.xxx.xxx..` at the top of the class!!

I lost 2 days trying to figure this out :(

Answer (score 0):

I've met the issue and work with these dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hiltVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hiltVersion"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hiltAndroidXVersion"
```

https://medium.com/gradeup/dependency-injection-dagger-hilt-vs-koin-ab2f7f85e6c6